# How to add vanilla .js to a custom Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, flatpickr

I'm trying to add a simple [date-picker](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr) to a custom vue component. I'm not using webpack so I want to avoid ready made `.vue` components and I rather understand how to add simple javascript to vue.

I'm following [this official vue tutorial](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html)

I've also seen [this codepen](https://codepen.io/apertureless/pen/vxWbqB?editors=1010) but I can't manage to make the date picker appear.

This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cosbgn/j4v3z6nk/2/):

Html:

```
<div class="app">
  <datepicker id='date-elem'></datepicker>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
Vue.component('date-picker', {
  extends: Flatpickr,
  mounted () {
    this.Flatpickr(date-elem, {})}
})
```

How can I easily integrate vanilla js in a Vue component without the need of .vue files, webpack etc?

Comment: IIRC, you'll want to build a directive.

Comment: But for example [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) vue example uses components, why you think is better a directive?

Comment: Vue ***IS*** Javascript, just pop it in a method and call this.methodName(), or **var lib = require('lib'); lib.method()**

Comment: But I tried something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cosbgn/ge9ruvbL/1/) but still nothing...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So you have a few misconceptions here. To make this a component (a very basic component), this is how you might do it.

In Vue, you're not going to typically extend an external Javascript library. What you will typically make is called a wrapper component. Essentially, a Vue component that handles all the interaction with the external library. In this case you want to use Flatpickr. From the [documentation](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/getting-started/), you need to use `new Flatpickr(element, options)`. So we can do that in the `mounted` event, passing `this.$el` which will point to the root Vue component element.

```
Vue.component('date-picker', {
    template: "<input type='text'>",
    mounted () {
        new Flatpickr(this.$el, {})
    }
})
```

Here is your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2h662gz6/).

But this component doesn't do very much. It just allows you to pick a date. To allow that date to be used *outside* the component, we want to extend it to support `v-model`. Here's how you might do that.

```
Vue.component('date-picker', {
    props:["value"],
    data(){
        return {
            selectedDate: this.value
        }
    },
    template: "<input type='text' v-model='selectedDate' @input='onInput'>",
    methods:{
        onInput(){
            this.$emit('input', this.selectedDate)
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        new Flatpickr(this.$el, {})
    }
})
```

Now, you can use it like this.

```
<date-picker v-model="selectedDate"></date-picker>
```

And selectedDate will receive the date you pick.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnaz90uf/) showing that.