# TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" Flatpickr & Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, flatpickr

I'm trying to wrap [flatpickr](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr) into a custom Vue component which should then should send dates to an eventHub, however I can't seems to get it to work. Somehow flatpickr can't find the input field (I think)

My wrapper component looks something like this:

```
<template>
<input type="text" id="flatpickr" placeholder="Select a range" />
</template>

<script>
const Flatpickr = require("flatpickr");

var defaultStart = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 10)).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
var defaultEnd = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)

export default {
  name: 'DatePicker',
  props:['startDate', 'endDate'], // I don't really need this but I should pass data to all Children
  mounted() {
    new Flatpickr('#flatpickr', {
      dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
      mode: 'range',
      altInput: true, // Human Readable
      minDate: new Date().fp_incr(-60), // 60 days from today
      maxDate: defaultEnd,
      // defaultDate: [defaultStart, defaultEnd],
      // minDate: '2017-01-01', // 60 days from today
      // maxDate: '2017-05-05',
      // defaultDate: ["2017-02-02", "2017-04-04"],
      locale: { firstDayOfWeek: 1},
      onClose: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
        let startDate = selectedDates[0].toISOString().slice(0, 10);
        let endDate = selectedDates[1].toISOString().slice(0, 10);
        this.$emit('change', { startDate, endDate });  // emit to eventHub
      }
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

I've also tried to use `.class-name` but nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How different is this from your last [question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682446/how-to-add-vanilla-js-to-a-custom-vue-component/43683190#43683190)? Could you not use that as a base? Here it looks like your $emit will fail because of a `this` issue.

Comment: No I know I really did try to use that even with $el, but the thing is not that $emit will fail is that flatpickr can't even find it's instance (it doesn't show) I just see an input element

Comment: You can replace $emit with console.log(startDate) for example, I really spent the whole day trying before posting it here (since its obviously veeeery similar)

Comment: Let me play with your new code using the old example. Ill get back to you.

Comment: This seems to work. https://jsfiddle.net/xnaz90uf/1/

Comment: Hi, so I tried to plug this in my code and it loads flatpicker to the whole template, my template is a nav bar where I also have the flatpicker, now the whole navbar is a big input..

Comment: Ok, then you need to use the $ref approach.

Comment: Yes, sorry my question was confusing. The `ref` works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the following changes:

### In the template...

```
<input type="text" ref="flatpickr" placeholder="Select a range" />
```

### In the mounted() hook...

```
mounted() {
    var myInput = this.$refs.flatpickr
    new Flatpickr(myInput, {
```

Explanation:

The Vue way of identifying elements in the template is by using "ref" (instead of "id") - and it's best to keep Vue happy because it does funky things with the template which may cause unexpected behaviours if you treat it as plain HTML. (It only *looks* like HTML but don't be fooled... the Vue template isn't HTML, and actually ends up getting compiled into a function.)

So, replace the input's id with a "ref" instead, and in your mounted() hook, get a variable reference to the input, and use that as the first parameter of your Flatpickr() call instead of an "#id".

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CookieJon/7stotLrz/2/

Comment: He doesn't really need a ref in this case, $el suffices.

Comment: Ok. I'm not familiar with Flatpickr, but if he adds more elements to the template, then he'll be forced to use "ref" instead of "el", I'm guessing??
  Either way, I suggest the OP reads up on both "$refs" and "$el" in the Vue docs because they're pretty fundamental...  $REFS: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref   $EL:  https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#el  Good luck!

Comment: You're correct and based on his comment, that turns out to be the case here.

Comment: Hi @Bumpy, yes this was the problem. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this vue component](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-flatpickr-component) instead.

---

Installation:

```
npm install vue-flatpickr-component --save
```

---

It is dead simple to use.

Sample:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <flat-pickr v-model="date"></flat-pickr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import flatPickr from 'vue-flatpickr-component';
  import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css';

  export default {    
    data () {
      return {
        date: null,       
      }
    },
    components: {
      flatPickr
    }
  }
</script>
```