# Importing Vanilla js file to Vue.js component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have previously made some drag and drop functionality in vanilla JS which I have used in other projects. Now I have started a Vue.js project and I would like to use the same drag and drop functionality.

Is it possible to include a vanilla JS file in a Vue.js component? And how can it be done?

So far I have only tried to add a `<script>` tag in the head element in the index.html but it throws an error.

```
<script src="../src/js/drag-and-drop.js"></script>
```

Comment: What kind of error? Can you also share your code?

Comment: Just a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" But that shows up no matter if the file is empty or not, I dont think that there is an issue with the file, just that it is imported or included in a wrong way.

Comment: Can you show how do you import it?

Comment: <script src="../src/js/drag-and-drop.js"></script>

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50159338/3200799)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can import the script within your vue component with either

1. #### import

   `import '../src/js/drag-and-drop.js';`
2. #### require

   `require('../src/js/drag-and-drop.js');`

in the script section of your component.

e.g.

```
<template>
  <!-- vue component markup -->
</template>

<script> 
import drag from '../src/js/drag-and-drop';
export default {
  name: 'you-vue-component',
}    
</script>
```

Comment: Yes true!
A good example is given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682446/how-to-add-vanilla-js-to-a-custom-vue-component

Comment: let me try this on my codebase